# ' was not declared in this scope' C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, sfml

I have some rude errors... I search the web about it, and i was able to read her everywhere, but still not fix my problem ...

Here is my **main** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Network.hpp"
#include "decode.hpp"
#include "listOfFunction.hpp"
#include "map.hpp"

void createSocket(){
    unsigned short bindPort = 12800;
    unsigned short clientPort;
    int ret = 0;
    sf::UdpSocket socket;
    sf::IpAddress clientAddr;
    sf::Packet packet;
    Map mainMap;

    if (socket.bind(bindPort) != sf::Socket::Done){
        if (sf::Socket::Error) std::cout << "An unexpected error happened : Fatal Error !" << std::endl;
        if (sf::Socket::NotReady) std::cout << "The socket is not ready to send/receive data yet !" << std::endl;
    }

    while(1){
        packet.clear();
        socket.receive(packet, clientAddr, clientPort);
        std::string header = readFromPacket(packet);
        ret = callFunction(packet, header, clientAddr, clientPort, mainMap, socket);
    }
}

int main(){
    createSocket();
}
```

Here are the errors :

> error : 'Map' was not declared in this scope 
>   error : expected ';'before 'mainMap' 
>   error : 'mainMap' was not declared in this scope
>   error : callFunction was not declared in this scope

**Map.cpp :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "SFML/Network.hpp"
#include "map.hpp"

Map::Map(){
    char number[5] = "\0";
    int m_obstacle[80000] = {0};
    std::string m_error = "not error";
    std::vector <int> m_posPlayer(0);
    std::vector <std::string> m_namePlayer(0);
    std::vector <sf::IpAddress> m_addressPlayer(0);
    std::string m_stringObstacle = "";
    for (int i=0;i<80000;i++){
        sprintf(number, "%d", m_obstacle[i]);
        m_stringObstacle += std::string(number) + "+";
    }
}

int Map::sendMap(sf::IpAddress address, unsigned short clientPort, sf::UdpSocket& socket){
    std::string header = "rcv_map";
    sf::Packet packet;
    packet >> header >> m_stringObstacle;
    if(socket.send(packet, address, clientPort)!=sf::UdpSocket::Done){
        m_error += "Error sending the packet \n";
    }
    return 0;
}

int Map::error(){
    if (m_error != "not_error"){
        std::cout << "here is a following list of errors : " << m_error << std::endl;
    }
    m_error.erase(0,m_error.length());
}
```

**Map.hpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Network.hpp"

#ifndef DECODE_H_INCLUDED
#define DECODE_H_INCLUDED

class Map{

    public:
        Map();
        int sendMap(sf::IpAddress address, unsigned short clientPort, sf::UdpSocket& socket);
        int error();

    private:
        int m_obstacle;
        std::vector <int> m_posPlayer;
        std::vector <int> m_namePlayer;
        std::vector <sf::IpAddress> m_addressPlayer;
        std::string m_stringObstacle;
};

#endif // DECODE_H_INCLUDED
```

The problem probably exists in the headers, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure that map.hpp available for compiler and really included to cpp files? Can you show how compiler is called?

Comment: You should put your `#include` statements *inside* your *include guards*.

Comment: If you use not Windows environment names of files are important : `Map.hpp` is not `map.hpp`

Answer (score 4):

> Problems are probably about headers, but can't find why.

That is absolutely right! You have applied [*inclusion guards*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) incorrectly.

You have used the inclusion guard from a wrong hpp file:

```
#ifndef DECODE_H_INCLUDED
```

in `map.hpp` comes from `decode.hpp`. It should be

```
#ifndef MAP_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is the right way to do. I just copyed the inclusion guard from another file, and i didn't notice it was name specific.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is related to these macro definitions in Map.hpp

```
#ifndef DECODE_H_INCLUDED
#define DECODE_H_INCLUDED
```

It seems they are the same definitions that are used in decode.hpp that is included before Map.hpp

Take into account that at least this constructor is wrong does not make sense and will not compile

```
Map::Map(){
    int i = 0;
    int m_obstacle[80000] = {0};
    std::vector <int> m_posPlayer(0);
    std::vector <std::string> m_namePlayer(0);
    std::vector <sf::IpAddress> m_addressPlayer(0);
    std::string m_stringObstacle = "";
    for (i=0;i<80000;i++){
        m_stringObstacle += m_obstacle[i] + "+";
   }
}
```

These local objects

```
    std::vector <int> m_posPlayer(0);
    std::vector <std::string> m_namePlayer(0);
    std::vector <sf::IpAddress> m_addressPlayer(0);
    std::string m_stringObstacle = "";
```

are not used.
I think you mean class data members instead of the local objects.:)

And this statement

```
    m_stringObstacle += m_obstacle[i] + "+";
```

is wrong and does not make sense.

Also data member

```
int m_obstacle;
```

is declared like a scalar object. You may not redeclare it in the constructor like an array.

Comment: @Xavier59 The code has other problems.  See my updated post.

Comment: I have no compilations errors here. Btw, i didn't try out this class for now, so this will probably happen. Not doubting that there is a problem, you probably point out that i can't append an integer to my string.  Then shoud I use itoa and then cast my char* to a string ? Or is there an easiest way ? Moreover, is "+=" accepted ? Thanks.

Comment: @Xavier59  There is no compilation error because formally the code is valid but it does not do what you expect.:)

Comment: @@Xavier59 For example in this statement m_stringObstacle += m_obstacle[i] + "+"; you get a local string that contains 8000 characters '+' and this string will be deleted after exiting the constructor. What is the sense of this statement?

Comment: This is exactly what i want. I expect something like "1+5+4+2+4+.....+"
But for sure, i will have to pass the int to string, not as this is in my code actually.
I want to build a string in order to send the "map" by a socket to a client. Each number is the id of a block. "+" is a separator, because the id can be superior to 9. I don't know if this is the best way do to it, so if you have others suppositions, i'm open to them ;)

Comment: I edited my post. Does that seems good to you for what I expect ? I'm worried, because as i don't empty the array, if I got 26 and then 3 from obstacle[i] (I know everythings is set to 0 actually but let's imagine), should i got 36 ? Thanks

Comment: @Xavier59 I do not see a sense in these manipulations because the local array      int m_obstacle[80000] = {0}; initialized by zeroes. What is the sense of declaring and using it in the constructor?

Comment: m_obstacle will change to some values, it is only temporar. But, are you trying to say that m_stringObstacle will not be save and will back to "" ? So, do I have to do a function just for build the string ?

Comment: @Xavier59 One more the array and the string are local variables of the constructor. they will be destroyed after exiting the constructor. There is no any sense to declare an array of 8000 elements that to use  one value 0.

Comment: why is m_stringObstacle only local ? I declared it on my .hpp

Comment: @  Xavier59 You declared local variable std::string m_stringObstacle = ""; in the constructor that hides the data member of the class with the same name.